# What is the configuration file read by init process in fedora 18?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, archlinux, fedora16

Just i want to check the configuration file used by init process in fedora 18 (32 bit). In older versions it is mentioned as /etc/inittab. Actually i found the file but i didn't get any info regarding configuration. it is saying that "inittab is no longer used when using systemd". If it is not the configuration file used by init process please mention the path where it is

Answer (score 0):

Yes as systemd is being used for setting runlevels and booting configuration you can check the configuration files in /etc/systemd/system/ directory where you find some target files for the different runlevels like graphical.target for runlevel 5.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker